# Update (repaint) application window (python)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside

LS,
I am developping an app that reads text from a web page. While the text is processed in the app the app window (gui) shows "application is not responding" (translated from a Dutch warning message). However the app is not frozen because I see it prints in the console window.
The app gui is designed in Qt designer and converted in python 2.7 code on win7 64 bit.
How can I force the app to refresh the window and update ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ways of doing it:

- Call your time consuming function in separate `thread` or create `timer`. Basic example with [`QTimer.singleShot`](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QTimer.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QTimer.singleShot):

  ```
  QTimer.singleShot(1, your_time_consuming_function)
  ```
- Call [`QCoreApplication.processEvents()`](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QCoreApplication.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents) in your text processing loop.

If all the time is spent in fetching the page, consider using timer or thread.

Comment: Thanks, the QCoreApplication.processEvents() keeps the GUI updated.

Comment: I think the first way (singleshot timer) cannot work